# JavaScript file don't load while other JavaScript files in same directory load correctly

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, spring-security, kendo-ui, thymeleaf

I am using Spring Boot 2.1.6.RELEASE , Thymeleaf 3, Spring Security

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.CacheControl;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * Configuration for overall application.
 */
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;
    }

    /**
     * Static resources.
     *
     * @param registry
     */
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        // Register resource handler for CSS and JS.
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/statics/", "D:/statics/")
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(2, TimeUnit.HOURS).cachePublic());
        // Register resource handler for images.
        registry.addResourceHandler(
                "/images/**",
                "/css/**",
                "/js/**"
        )
                .addResourceLocations(
                        "classpath:/static/images/",
                        "classpath:/static/css/",
                        "classpath:/static/js/"
                )
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(2, TimeUnit.HOURS).cachePublic());
    }

}
```

In `header.html` (Thymeleaf template file)

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/kendo.messages.vi-VN.js}"><!--this file cannot load--></script>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/jquery.min.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/kendo.all.min.js}"></script>
```

3 JavaScript files: `/js/kendo.messages.vi-VN.js` , `/js/jquery.min.js` , and `/js/kendo.all.min.js` I put in same directory.

File `/js/jquery.min.js` and `/js/kendo.all.min.js` load success. While file `/js/kendo.messages.vi-VN.js` cannot access

How to fix it?